# OpenCV: Multiple Lines Detected for Rectangular Edges and Incorrect 'y' Edge Drawing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform

I'm working with the OpenCV library in Python and trying to detect the long and short edges of a rectangular shape in an image. I have used the Canny edge detector and then applied the Hough transform to detect the lines. However, I am encountering an issue where the output is detecting multiple lines of the same length, and it is not drawing the 'y' edge correctly.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Asus Hn004W\Desktop\1.jpeg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 78, 106, apertureSize=3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 200)

for r_theta in lines:
    arr = np.array(r_theta[0], dtype=np.float64)
    r, theta = arr
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*r
    y0 = b*r

    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would like to understand why multiple lines of the same length are being detected and why the 'y' edge is not being drawn correctly. What modifications should I make to the code to accurately detect and draw the edges of the rectangular shape?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4p10.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> multiple lines

All results with votes above the threshold will be returned from `HoughLines()`.

So, you should employ some post-process to decide your result from them.
Process called "Non maximum suppression" is often employed.

> not drawing the 'y' edge correctly

Perhaps, your threshold (`200`) is too large for vertical lines (or canny result is not good).